# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect()

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to set up FTP SSL connection in PHP.  I have used `ftp_connect()` fine and works great.  As soon as I try to use `ftp_ssl_connect()`, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect()

I do have openssl extension turned on in PHP extentions.  I am not sure what else there is to do as searching google there is nothing that I can find to do to make this function call work.  Does anyone know when what I am missing or to check to see if something else needs to be installed on my wampserver?

Here is my php code I am using:

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server); 
$ftp_user_name = "username"; 
$ftp_user_pass = "password"; 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!"; 
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else { 
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name"; 
}
```

It obviously doesn't get past the first line because of saying that `ftp_ssl_connect()` is an undefined function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/ftp_ssl_connect):

> Note: Why this function may not exist
> ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the OpenSSL support is built statically into php, this means that on Windows this function will be undefined in the official PHP builds. To make this function available on Windows you must compile your own PHP binaries.

> Note:
> ftp_ssl_connect() **is not intended for use with sFTP**. To use sFTP with PHP, please see [**ssh2_sftp()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php).

(BTW: I don't use Windows but I can't access to `ftp_ssl_connect()`)

Comment: Okay I am going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

PHP7.1.12 CentOS

I build php by myself.

```
/usr/local/php71/bin/php -r "ftp_ssl_connect('server1.example.com');"

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect() in Command line code:1
```

resolve：

```
# /root/php-7.1.12/ is php source dir
cd /root/php-7.1.12/ext/ftp/

# /usr/local/php71/ is php dir
/usr/local/php71/bin/phpize

# the param --with-openssl-dir is very important
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php71/bin/php-config --with-openssl-dir

make
make install

vim /usr/local/php71/lib/php.ini
# add last line
extension=ftp.so

service php-fpm reload
```

check：

```
# method 1
/usr/local/php71/bin/php -r "phpinfo();" | grep FTP

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled

# method 2
/usr/local/php71/bin/php -r "ftp_ssl_connect('server1.example.com');"

PHP Warning:  ftp_ssl_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Command line code on line 1
```

done!